# How can I recover my mentions from Twitter?

Tags: twitter, twitter-integration, twitter-api

When I search for my mentions on Twitter almost all of them had disappeared. I used to have around 50, and then only 1 remained, after that I got one new, and instead of having 2 now, the previous one got deleted.

Any idea how to solve this?

By the way I have [Backupify](http://www.backupify.com/) which stored all those mentions, but I can not retrieve them automatically to my Twitter account.

Can this be done?

If so how?

Answer (score 1):

You need to file a [Twicket](https://support.twitter.com/forms) or direct message (dm) [@Support](http://twitter.com/support)

Comment: I added a ticket, thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

Did you try searching on twitter for @username ?

Comment: Yes, but It did not work, thanks

Comment: I am not sure of any other services :(